# Error using json_encode in php

Tags: php, json

I'm having some trouble when I try to use php's JSON encode function

what I'm doing:

```
echo json_encode($ppar, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

now the variable $ppar is an associative array with a whole bunch of data in it. I can get it to work with out the added parameter, but not with it, and when I looked up on php.net it does say there that the 2nd parameter is valid so I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

this works (except for the fact everything is squished together):

```
echo json_encode($ppar);
```

but this:

```
echo json_encode($ppar, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

gives me this error:

> Warning: json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/www/mysite/pp.php on line 10

and the output is null.
I've been going to this for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be running a PHP version prior to `5.3`. Since the doc states that is when it was introduced.

Also, `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` was added in `5.4`. So even though options will work on 5.3, PRETTY_PRINT won't

Comment: I just noticed it was using 5.2 I was able to get my host to upgrade to 5.3.6 and I no longer get the error message but still a null output. so I'm going to go with the answer that it was introduced in 5.4

Answer (score 3):

The "options" parameter (which you set to JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) was added in PHP 5.3.0 - you are probably using a version of PHP older than that.